# Practical guidance on setting up and getting started with Selendroid?

Tags: selendroid

I am a new user and have never used Selenium although have read lots on the official site. The amount of manual checks, versions and incomplete or add-ons are quite daunting to someone coming in for the first time. I Have knowledge of C++ and a software development background but i am struggling in the field of web testing (coming from embedded electronics which was almost a science).

Can someone help with a PRACTICAL how to guide on Selendroid? Examples would be:

1. Download and install (easy this one)
2. Setup install
3. Launch 1st App
4. Framework environment

There are so many you tubers and each video is a different build, platform or for a different programming language. Good software developers always have standard best practiсes. I am used to the professionalism of perforce and quite frankly, the open source (and not corporate paid license world) is far more messier and (i think harder) to learn new technologies.

Comment: check this link http://selendroid.io/setup.html#getAut

Comment: Selendroid is great and all but if you want to also automate iOS at some point, try Appium instead. Here is a [Appium+Java+Amazon Device Farm](http://timothycope.com/java-appium-automation) step-by-step guide I wrote. I also have a [Appium+C#+SauceLabs framework](https://github.com/kirbycope/c-sharp-appium) in my GitHub. Just supply your own .apk to test.